# Docker compiling of image error 'file does not exist'

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to create a docker image with a Rust binary, small cli app I made. My docker build command errors when I try to run it with:

```
sudo docker build -t image/tag .
```

Error:

```
    Step 6/8 : COPY --from=builder /volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux- 
    musl/release/async_web_scraper .

    COPY failed: stat volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux- 
    musl/release/async_web_scraper: file does not exist
```

I am using the static linking method with `musl`. This is my Dockerfile:

```
   WORKDIR /volume
   COPY . .
   RUN cargo build --release

   FROM alpine
   COPY --from=builder /volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux- 
   musl/release/async_web_scraper .
   WORKDIR /async-root-dir
   ENTRYPOINT [ "/async_web_scraper" ]
```

I feel like I am close. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: looks like `RUN cargo build --release` is not producing the output you expect. There is no such file at `/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/async_web_scraper`

Comment: @TheFool got you. Any idea what I can try? I am fairly new to docker.

Comment: you could build only that builder stage with `docker build --target builder --tag test .` and then you go inside and inspect the filesystem. `docker run -ti test sh`

Comment: Running those cmds gives me this file structure
`# ls
Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml Dockerfile  src  target`

Comment: you should be inside the volume dir since you set it as workdir. -now move around the filesystem and look in the places you expect the output to be. Maybe also run your cargo command by hand inside and see what it produces.

Comment: @TheFool yes you were right, the final dir `/async_web_scraper` does not exist and the bin files are at `/release` . If I make the copy cmd now `COPY --from=builder /volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux- 
   musl/release` it doesn't error when I build. But what should my `ENTRYPOINT` be? `ENTRYPOINT [ "./" ]` perhaps? It errors when I run it.

Comment: If your scapers takes arguments use `ENTRYPOINT ["./async_web_scraper" "$@"]` so that you can pass the additional arguments to the binary like `docker run scraper http://mywebpage -some-other-arg` otherwise use a CMD `CMD ["./async_web_scaper"]`. If you copy the binary to something like /usr/bin then you can also leave the path of since the binary will be systemwide available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240098/discussion-between-godhar-and-the-fool).